# Shiny read.transactions not showing output after upload

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, reactive-programming

My code just not working at all, no error after upload my file. `ui.r`

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel("APRIORI"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      h2("Davin", align = "center", style = "color:blue"),
      fileInput('gg', 'Choose CSV File', accept=c('.csv')),
      plotOutput("imagegro")

    ),

    mainPanel(
      dataTableOutput("apriori"),
      plotOutput("tops")
    )
  )
))
```

The Server `server.r`

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  library(arules)
  output$tops <- renderPrint({
  dong <- input$gg

  if (is.null(dong)) return(NULL)

  # grocer <- read.csv(CSSSV$datapath)
  groceries <- read.transactions(dong$datapath, sep = ",")

  # groceries <- read.transactions("jual.csv", sep = ",")
  # default settings result in zero rules learned
  apriori(groceries)

  # set better support and confidence levels to learn more rules
  groceryrules <- apriori(groceries, parameter = list(support =
                                                        0.2, confidence = 0.76))
  # writing the rules to a CSV file
  write(groceryrules, file = "groceryrules.csv",
        sep = ",", quote = TRUE, row.names = FALSE)

  # converting the rule set to a data frame
  groceryrules_df <- as(groceryrules, "data.frame")
  output$imagegro <- renderPlot(image(groceries))
  topconfidence <- sort(groceryrules, decreasing = TRUE, na.last = NA, by = "confidence")
  topconfidence_df <- as(topconfidence, "data.frame")
  output$apriori <- renderDataTable(topconfidence_df)
  })

})
```

[Running in Web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pgi3D.png)

[Rstudio, no error. no respond](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jpico.png)

is shiny upload do not support read.transactions ?
can someone tell code that use read.transactions after upload shiny...
my file `jual.csv`

```
broccoli,corn,green pepper
asparagus,corn,squash
bean,corn,squash,tomato
bean,corn,green pepper,tomato
asparagus,bean,broccoli
asparagus,bean,squash,tomato
corn,tomato
broccoli,green pepper,tomato
asparagus,bean,squash
bean,corn
bean,broccoli,green pepper,squash
asparagus,bean,squash
asparagus,bean,corn,squash
bean,broccoli,corn,green pepper,tomato
```

Help Please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to study how Shiny works. It is a **reactive** programming language which is very different than conventional programming. You basically have to set up a set of nodes that are interdependent and update each other when needed. A good place to start is Joe Cheng (the author of Shiny's) presentations - here is an intro [Intro to Shiny](https://www.r-bloggers.com/joe-cheng-presents-shiny/), but he has some newer more advanced ones too.

Anyway, this probably is what you were looking for:

```
library(shiny)
library(arules)

u <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("APRIORI"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      h2("Davin", align = "center", style = "color:blue"),
      fileInput('gg', 'Choose CSV File', accept=c('.csv')),
      plotOutput("imagegro")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      dataTableOutput("apriori"),
      verbatimTextOutput("aprioritxt")
    )
)))
s <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  groceries <- reactive({
    req(input$gg)
    read.transactions(input$gg$datapath, sep = ",")
  })
  groceryrules <- reactive({
    grules <- apriori(groceries(), parameter = list(support = 0.2, confidence = 0.76))
    write(grules, file = "groceryrules.csv", sep = ",", quote=TRUE, row.names=FALSE)
    grules
  })
  groceryrules_df <- reactive({
    as(groceryrules(), "data.frame")
  })
  topconfidence_df <- reactive({
    topconfidence <- sort(groceryrules(), decreasing=TRUE, na.last=NA, by="confidence")
    topconfidence_df <- as(topconfidence, "data.frame")
  })
  output$aprioritxt <- renderPrint({  print(apriori(groceries()))  })
  output$imagegro <- renderPlot({image(groceries())})
  output$apriori <- renderDataTable({topconfidence_df()})
})
# options(shiny.reactlog = TRUE) # see visualizer notes below
shinyApp(u,s)
```

Looks like this:

[image]

It may help to visualize the nodes - this is what the Shiny reactive log visualizer that visualizes the nodes showing at the end of the log playback:

[image]

Instructions on using this tool can be found here:[Reactive Log Visualizer](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/showReactLog.html)

Notes on this tool:

- It is enabled with the line `options(shiny.reactlog = TRUE)` inserted before the `shinyApp` call
- It causes a log to be recorded of how the nodes activate each other.
- The log visualizer can then be enabled with Ctrl-F3 (or Command-F3)
- You can then move back in forth in the log (basically you are moving in time in the log) with the arrow keys.
- The reactive symbols are explained here: [Shiny Reactivity Overview](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/reactivity-overview.html)
- It exposes a lot of reactive activity that is invisible to the user so it can be confusing.
- It does not work well on large Shiny applications - many aspects of this tool simply do not scale.

Comment: Thanks ! Mike Wise

Comment: upvote need 15 reps, this website really are something

Comment: You've got 15 rep.

Comment: i just get it 2 hours ago, so i am new to this upvote thing, i already upvote you right ?

Comment: right, okay, didn't see that. If you have an different color uparrow on my answer then you did upvote it.